# Backbone Marionette composite view's items view each has a form. How to use jQuery deferred to do something after each is submitted successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette composite view where each child item view has its own form.

```
var DependentsFormFields = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: 'dependents_form_fields_wrapper',
    itemViewContainer: '#dependents',
    itemView: DependentsFormFields,
    events: {
        "click #save-dependent-section" : "saveSection"
    },
    saveSection: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.children.each(function(childView){
            childView.submitForm();
        });
    }
});

var DependentsFormFields = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: 'dependent_form',
    submitForm: function() {
        var _this = this;

        var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(_this);

        _this.model.save(data, {
            url: _this.model.urlRoot,
            success: function() {
                App.Components.Form.ErrorHandler.removeErrors({
                    view: _this
                });
            },
            error: function(model, response) {
                App.Components.Form.ErrorHandler.applyErrors({
                    view: _this,
                    errorData: JSON.parse(response.responseText)
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That all works grand. But now there is a requirement that after the Dependents section is saved an 'amount due' needs to be recalculated. Elsewhere in the code I have that handled with `App.execute("recalculate:amount:due");`

I'm struggling to understand how to use jQuery's deferred (or promises or when...) to wrap the `this.children.each` in the `saveSection` function of composite view so that once all of the child sections are save, then the command and be vented out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

First, your `submitForm` needs to return the deferred:

```
submitForm: function() {
    // same var declarations

    return _this.model.save(data, {
        // same code
    });
}
```

Then, store each deferred, and calculate the amount due when they're all done.

```
saveSection: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var deferreds = [];
    this.children.each(function(childView){
        deferreds.push(childView.submitForm());
    });

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function(){
      // calculate amount due
    });
}
```

If you're unclear on how deferreds work, you might want to check out 2 blog posts I wrote on the subject:

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/02/rendering-a-view-after-multiple-async-functions-return-using-promises/

Comment: This only sort of worked. It always fell into the .done even if the save failed with an error.

Comment: That means that either you `submitForm` is returning a 20X status even when failing, of it's returning a non-deferred value (e.g. if client-side validation fails and it returns false).

Answer (score 0):

**The solution I ended up with:**

After some research and testing it seemed that backbone models don't follow the deferred pattern itself. Sometimes you can tap into promises in the ajax that backbone sync defers to. It wasn't reliable though.

I ended up implementing the [Backbone Deferred](https://github.com/arhea/backbone-deferred) plugin.

```
var Person = Backbone.Deferred.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: App.apiRoot + '/Person'
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Enrollment.Person
});

var DependentsFormFields = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: 'dependents_form_fields_wrapper',
    itemViewContainer: '#dependents',
    itemView: DependentsFormFields,
    events: {
        "click #save-dependent-section" : "saveSection"
    },
    saveSection: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.children.each(function(childView){
            childView.submitForm();
        });

        var promises = [];
        this.children.each(function(view){
            promises.push( view.submitForm() );
        });

        $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
            App.execute("recalculate:enrollment:subscription:rate");
        });

    }
});

var DependentsFormFields = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: 'dependent_form',
    submitForm: function() {
        var _this = this;

        var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(_this);

        return _this.model.save(data, {
            url: _this.model.urlRoot,
            success: function() {
                App.Components.Form.ErrorHandler.removeErrors({
                    view: _this
                });
            },
            error: function(model, response) {
                App.Components.Form.ErrorHandler.applyErrors({
                    view: _this,
                    errorData: JSON.parse(response.responseText)
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```